# A list of data from a DB showed in the form of LinkButtons list- How to achieve this in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I'm making a photographer website.  It retrieves the categories of the images and show it as a list of link buttons.  The user can click on a certain link buttons to show that categories images.

I thought of adding a `BulletedList` and then dynamically adding those link buttons to it, but it produces and error that I can't nest controls inside the list item.

This was what I attempted to do:

```
<div id="gallery_wrapper">
    <div id="cat_wrapper" runat="server">
        <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text=""><asp:LinkButton runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:BulletedList>
    </div>
    <div id="img_wrapper" runat="server">test_img</div>
</div>
```

But it produces this parse error:

> Parser Error Message: The 'Text' property of 'asp:ListItem' does not allow child objects.

My question is how can I show category names that are retrieved from a DB in the form of a list of link buttons?

Comment: Where's the code you already have? It sounds like you're fairly close and we wouldn't have to change it much to answer this question.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Unfortunately, i can't think of a code to do this. Because i don't know whta's the proper tool to use in the first place.

Comment: `i thought of add BulletedList and then dynamically add those link buttons to it, but it produces and error that i can't nest controls inside the list item.` Where did that code go?

Comment: to get a good help, put your code that does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you stated that you're really a beginner at this, I think the most helpful thing would be to point you in the right direction for documentation.

That said, I'd start with the MSDN introduction to ASP.NET [Data Bound Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-bound-controls)

There are more than enough approaches in this one page to choose from.  Personally, I'd use a [Repeater control, or a DataList control](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-cs).  (Code samples for both in the linked article.)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a repeater to solve this problem. I would check out [this article](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater) for information on using a repeater. However there are many ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Repeater control instead of BulletedList.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <ul>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" /></li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </ul>
</FooterTemplate>
```